# How can I tell which version of MSI is running on my machine?

Tags: windows-installer

How can I tell which version of MSI is running on my machine?

Thank you,
Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start -> Run, type `msiexec.exe`

Version is on the top of the information in the opening window.

Comment: I get:  Windows ® Installer. V 5.0.7600.16385   Bu I am looking at a setup.ini file which searches for version numbers 1.1, 1.2, 2.0 and 3.0  How do those reconcile?

Comment: what lines of the setup.ini in particular?

Comment: [SupportOSMsi11] ;Supported platforms for MSI 1.1
Win95=1
Win98=1
WinNT4SP3=1

Comment: I believe thats just the Major.Minor numbers of the installer. Also the [SupportOSMsi11] section is probably being used by MsiVersion check. The section only lists what OS supports MSI 1.1

Comment: For example, the line you posted simply means that MSI 1.1.xxx is supported by Windows 95, 98, NT4 with SP3 etc. You will also find individual sections later on like [Win95] that defines specific release version of the OS that is required (for example Windows 95, release 5.0 would have MajorVer=5 MinorVer=0 etc under [Win95])